# Magento2 remove All Previous addresses on checkout page when selecting shipping address

Tags: magento2

When i checkout as a logged in user, and if i have added my address in an earlier purchase, i am presented with previous addresses which i have entered on checkout page. I want to add fresh address each time even i am logged in and i have already default addresses.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1: Always shows the address form**

In order to archive this, you will have to tell Magento to not load the address-list. To do this, you can create a fallback to the `Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list.js` in your theme and changes its content to:

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'ko',
], function (ko) {
    'use strict';

    return ko.observableArray([]);
});
```

**To take away:** Keep in mind it won't prevent Magento to keep saving new addresses to the customer account, it just tells to knockoutjs that the address-list is an empty array.

**Case 2: Only shows the default addresses**

In this do the fallback to `Magento_Customer/js/model/customer-addresses.js`

And change it's content to only push to the list items that `default_billing` or `default_shipping` is `true`.

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    './customer/address'
], function ($, ko, Address) {
    'use strict';

    var isLoggedIn = ko.observable(window.isCustomerLoggedIn);

    return {
        /**
         * @return {Array}
         */
        getAddressItems: function () {
            var items = [],
                customerData = window.customerData;

            if (isLoggedIn()) {
                if (Object.keys(customerData).length) {
                    $.each(customerData.addresses, function (key, item) {
                        // Only push the default items
                        if (item.default_billing || item.default_shipping) {
                            items.push(new Address(item));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            return items;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks @Ziru Zanrgeiff

Comment: i replaced this js file in my theme here
 app / design / frontend /Vendor / theme / Magento_Customer / js / model / address-list.js
but it does not work.

Comment: Hi, take into consideration after that you have to clean up your previous compiled theme and compile it again. I have tested it before posting here and it was working fine.

Comment: the only problem is i have to make changes to core file address-list.js, i want to replace it with theme file.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean when I told you to fallback to that file.